# Am I encrypting my passwords correctly in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, encryption

I have a security class:

```
 public class security
{
    private static string createSalt(int size)
    {
        //Generate a random cryptographic number
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] b = new byte[size];
        rng.GetBytes(b);

        //Convert to Base64
        return Convert.ToBase64String(b);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generate a hashed password for comparison or create a new one
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pwd">Users password</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string createPasswordHash(string pwd)
    {
        string salt = "(removed)";
        string saltAndPwd = string.Concat(pwd, salt);
        string hashedPwd =
            FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(
            saltAndPwd, "sha1");

        return hashedPwd;
    }
}
```

This works fine, but I am wondering if it is sufficient enough.

Also, is this next block of code better? Overkill?

```
static byte[] encrInitVector = new byte[] { 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x90, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF };

static string encrKey = "(removed)";

public static string EncryptString(string s)
{
    byte[] key;

    try
    {
        key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encrKey.Substring(0, 8));

        DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

        byte[] inputByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateEncryptor(key, encrInitVector), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);

        cs.FlushFinalBlock();

        return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the last is the best,, overkill is always good,, but just take a look at this image.

- [image]

If your site is not a large shopping store or bank or something of that magnitude that you do need strong security then your first code if sufficient enough. (If you do have user security high then I would also recommend SSL.)

Comment: Ok, but you need to ask how large is my application and how secure is it needed to be. Like I said, A bank site needs more security then a forum.